# SSPI error and DotNetMethod exception while connecting to the SQL DB using powershell script

Tags: sql-server, authentication, powershell

I wrote the following script with the original connection names and credentials.

```
$SQLServer = "servername" 
$SQLDBName = "dbname"
$SqlQuery = "select * from tbl_Employee "

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName;
User ID= xyz; Password= abc; trusted_connection=true;"

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection

$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd

$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
```

After hitting enter I get the following error:

```
Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s) :"Cannot generate SSPI context."
At line:1 char:17
+$SqlAdapter.Fill <<<< ($DataSet)
+CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: (:)[],MethodInvocationException
+FullyQualifiedErrorId: DotNetMethodException
```

I am trying to connect to the client's database using the given credentials but with the above code, its taking the windows credentials by default.

Answer (score 2):

Connection String should instead read:

DRIVER=SQL Server;Server=$SQLServer;Database=$SQLDBName;UID=xyz;PWD=abc;

Answer (score 2):

As you state you are trying to connect with specific credentials the problem is with your connection string.

As you use the following connection string:

```
Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName;User ID= xyz; Password= abc; trusted_connection=true;
```

You will always be using `Windows Authentication`.

They key here is that you add

```
trusted_connection=true
```

Which will take precedence over the username and password combination.

Please see this blog post on MSDN [Connectionstrings, mixing usernames and windows authentication. Who goes first?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2008/11/14/connectionstrings-mixing-usernames-and-windows-authentication-who-goes-first.aspx)

Which clearly states

> If “With Integrated Windows Authentication” is selected, this will
>   takes precedence over the username/password in the connection string.

So the solution to your problem would be to remove the `trusted_connection` part

`Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName;User ID= xyz; Password= abc`;